# How to Install Sharepoint 2013 Powershell Module on Windows 10 Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How to Install Sharepoint 2013 Powershell Module on Windows 10 Powershell?

Any Help will be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to install SharePoint PowerShell explicitly in SharePoint Server.. it is part of SharePoint server installation,automatically you will get SharePoint PowerShell, it is applicable to all on-premise versions of SharePoint like 2010, 2013, 2016 and so on.

In the Start menu, just type "SharePoint"  then you will get all sharepoint related products installed in your machine or server, there you will **SharePoint PowerShell.**

While executing the script at the beginning of the script, you need to include this line :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
```

Comment: Op is asking how to install the SharePoint PowerShell snap-in on a workstation, not on the  SharePoint server itself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to the [SharePoint Server Cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-server/sharepoint-server-cmdlets) which are part of the SharePoint server installation itself. You can't install these on your client computer as they require local server access to perform operations.

A very good alternative that you *can* install is [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps), you can install that simply by entering (for SharePoint 2013):

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2013
```

You can use the following reference to see supported cmdlets: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps#cmdlet-overview

Search for "SharePoint Server 2013" on that page and you will see which ones applies to your environment.